# Is overriding dependency prodivers considered bad practice?

Tags: python, design-patterns, dependency-injection, d

I am reimplementing something like Python [Dependency Injector](http://python-dependency-injector.ets-labs.org/) in D programming language. I want to build a pure dependency injection framework for D.

Is [overriding of providers](http://python-dependency-injector.ets-labs.org/providers/overriding.html) considered bad practice? It seems that overriding of providers is clearly a nonlocal dependency and nonlocal dependencies are usually considered a bad practice by OOP theoretics.

So should I or should I not implement overriding of providers in my pure dependency injection framework for D?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no standard DI support in D. By standard I mean - the DI framework is not part of the D standard library. Therefore it is entirely up to you how you implement it. I only briefly scanned through the Python Dependency Injector project you mentioned and apart from some python-specific things I see no reason why a good DI framework implemented in D can't be done the same way. The "providers" name reminds me of how Java SPI works, which is what we (I am a Java developer as well) use for decades, and it is proven to be a good approach.

Your question is confusing little bit because overriding has a special meaning in D. In my humble opinion, users of your DI framework should be able to plug in different, but *compatible* provider, as long as these providers give objects of the same type (implement some interface that your class needs).

I said above that there is no standard DI framework in the standard library, but it is worth saying that there are DI frameworks for D done by other members of the D community. One of them is the excellent (Spring-like) Poodinis framework: https://github.com/mbierlee/poodinis . Have a look and see whether it fits your needs.